# PHP function is_executable returns false even though the file is definitely executable

Tags: php, selinux

I'm using PHP 5.3.

Using getfacl the files permissions are:

```
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

I also am having problems using PHP's Program execution Functions, http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

The program in question is wkhtmltopdf and I have it in my /usr/bin directory.

I have the convert program in my /usr/bin directory with the exact same permissions and the is_executable function returns true.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code that returns false?

Comment: Does `is_file($file)` to the one that is not executable returns true?, maybe you misspelled the name...

Comment: <pre><?php var_dump(is_executable('/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/print/lib/wkhtmltopdf')); ?></pre>
<pre><?php var_dump(is_executable('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf')); ?></pre>
<pre><?php var_dump(is_executable('/usr/bin/convert')); ?></pre>

Comment: is_file returns true so no misspell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I solved this.  The problem was selinux policies standing in the way.  I used the Security Context from /usr/bin/convert and used the chcon command to apply the same security context to /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 6):

For me the answer was to create a policy module to allow wkhtmltopdf to run without disabling SELinux:

1. `sudo su -` (run as root to make the next steps simpler)
2. `tail -F /var/log/audit.log | grep wkhtml > wkhtml.audit` (leave
   this running and continue to next step)
3. try to load your web page that attempts to create a pdf, it will fail as before but now we are
   logging.
4. CTRL+C to stop the process from step 2 *(can skip to 7 if in
   a hurry, but it's strongly suggested you use these review steps before making
   selinux exceptions permanent!)*
5. `cat wkhtml.audit | audit2allow -m
   wkhtmltopdf > wkhtmltopdf.te`
6. review the wkhtmltopdf.te file to
   make sure new rules will be sensible. you will probably see "allow
   httpd_t self:process execmem" and possibly "allow httpd_t var_t:file
   read" depending on your setup
7. `cat wkhtml.audit | audit2allow -M
   wkhtmltopdf`
8. `semodule -i wkhtmltopdf.pp` (might take a minute,
   be patient)

You should now be able to load the pdf-creating page without error. If not, we have likely fixed one problem and arrived at another--might need to repeat steps. Tail to wkhtml.audit2 this time and cat it with the original when making a new module (or else you'll be undoing first fix!):

`tail -F ... > wkhtml.audit2`

if audit2 is empty, there is a non-selinux problem.  otherwise:

`cat wkhtml.audit wkhtml.audit2 | audit2allow ...`